# Creating a lite version, using multiple targets, how do you avoid overwriting the full version?

Tags: ios, xcode, testflight

I'm using the strategy of multiple targets to create a lite version of an iOS app. On testing via Xcode, in the simulator and on my device when running a build it creates a new icon for the lite version. The full version and lite version sit next to each, and no overwriting appears to happen.

However a remote tester, downloading via Test Flight, reported that when installing the lite version, it overwrote their full version. When they then upgraded back to the full version - full version is in the app store, the lite version is no - it overwrote back to the full version. How do I avoid this?

**Update**

It appears I need custom app ids, what is the best way to implement/check this?

Comment: Do they have different App ids?

Comment: You need two separate Info.plist files each with a different bundle id.

Answer (score 2):

You need to create a custom app id for your Lite version.

Edit :

On your target, you need to change the Bundle Identifier.

[image: Example on your targets]

Comment: Where do I create this custom app id?

Comment: I modify my answer with an example.